# Error starting a function inside of an if statement

Tags: python, function

I have a def running inside of an if function, but when it's supposed to start it doesn't. Below is a copy of the code I wrote. Before I had the if statement for the two games, it ran just fine just as a single def.

```
print("Please choose from one of the following: \n")
print("1. Tic-Tac-Toe. \n")
print("2. Number Guessing Game. \n")
playerQuestion = input("")
print("You have selected game " + playerQuestion + "! Starting the game up. . . ")
sleep(2)
if playerQuestion == 1:
    print("1")


    def guessingGame():

        for i in range(5):
            print("")
            playerGuess = ()
            computerNumber = (randrange(100))

            playerGuess = int(input("I am thinking of a number... Please make your first guess! "))

            tries = 1

        while playerGuess != computerNumber:
            tries += 1
            if (playerGuess > computerNumber):
                print("Lower! \n")
                playerGuess = ()
                playerGuess = int(input("I am thinking of a number... Please make your next guess! "))
            elif (playerGuess < computerNumber):
                print("Higher! \n")
                playerGuess = ()
                playerGuess = int(input("I am thinking of a number... Please make your next guess! "))
        if playerGuess == computerNumber:
            tries = str(tries)
            print("You got it in " + tries + " tries! Congratulations! ")
            again = str(input("Do you want to play again (type yes or no): "))
            again = again.lower()
            again = again[:1]
            if again == "y":
                guessingGame()
            else:
                sleep(1)
                print("Thank you for playing! ")


    guessingGame()

    sleep(10)
else:
    def TicTacToe():

        board = [
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9],
        ]
        for i in range(5):
            print(board)
```

Comment: Apparently `playerQuestion` is not equal to `1`.

Comment: Hi, welcome here, try to write a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Yopu really should define functions on top-level at the beginning of your code and not somewhere in the middle.

Comment: you enter "1" which is not equal to 1, and you never call for tic tac toe function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
if playerQuestion == '1':
```

Comment: I appreciate it, I guess I had entirely glanced over that when re-reading my code